# Paste data from the first empty line of a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to paste datas from a workbook into another one. I need to import those datas on the first empty line of a column. Since this column may contain blank cells, I have to determine the first empty line thanks to another column in which no blank cells is possible.

I wrote this code:

=> To determine first empty line:

```
Dim n
With Worksheets("Dest")
n = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row + 1
End With
```

=> To paste at the right position:

```
For j = 0 To (finas - debutas)
Worksheets("Dest").Cells(n, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
Next j
```

But the system keeps pasting the datas on the first line...
What did I do wrong ?

Thanks for answers ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing `n` in your loop.

```
For j = 0 To (finas - debutas)
  Worksheets("Dest").Cells(n, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
  n=n+1
Next j

'or

For j = 0 To (finas - debutas)
  Worksheets("Dest").Cells(n+j, debutad + j) = Vcol(j)
Next j
```